# Order by month and then by day of month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to order first by month and then by day of the month. This is how my query looks right now:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(`Datum Bezoek 1`, '%e %M') AS `DATE`, sum(GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'GF') + sum(GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'SB') + sum(GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'VIA') AS PA, sum(PB = 1) AS PB, sum(PG = 1) AS PG, sum(GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'GF') AS GF, sum(GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'SB') AS SB, sum(GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'VIA') AS VIA, sum(Blanco = 1) AS Blanco, `Segment No_ PST` AS Segment, Deelgebied AS Area
from `psttodo-uit`
where `Hostess Code` = 010 and DATE(`afgewerkt tablet datum`) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2014-05-01', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2014-06-20', '%Y-%m-%d')
group by DATE_FORMAT(`Datum Bezoek 1`, '%e %M'), Deelgebied
order by DATE_FORMAT(`Datum Bezoek 1`, '%e %M')
```

But my result looks now like this:

```
10 June
10 June
12 June
12 May
12 May
13 June
13 May
```

How can I make sure that the result is like this:

```
12 May
12 May
13 May
10 June
10 June
12 June
13 June
```

I've tried to do this:

```
order by MONTH(DATE_FORMAT(`Datum Bezoek 1`, '%e %M')), DAYOFMONTH(DATE_FORMAT(`Datum Bezoek 1`, '%e %M'))
```

but gave even more mixed results.

Comment: Change order by to `order by DATE_FORMAT(`Datum Bezoek 1`, '%e %M'), DATE_FORMAT(`Datum Bezoek 1`, '%e %c')`

Comment: you have to order by the timestamp of the date.

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` returns a string. I assume your `Datum Bezoek 1` column is of `DATE` or `DATE_TIME` type, so you should be able to use ORDER BY `Datum Bezoek 1`.